# Show a message after a few seconds hover using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question:

When the user hovers over a certain part of text I want a message to display after a few seconds. I would ideally want it all in CSS if it is possible but Javascript is also fine.

### For example: Let's say the user hovers over the word book. After 2 seconds a message pops up saying something like "books are read by everyone".

What I've tried

I looked into Tooltip where you can display messages on hover

**Html**

```
    <div class="tooltip">Book
      <span class="tooltiptext">Books are read by everyone</span>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
.tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;

      /* Position the tooltip */
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
    }



.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
<div class="tooltip">Book
      <span class="tooltiptext">Books are read by everyone</span>
    </div>




<!-- end snippet -->
```

However, I don't know how to display the Tooltip after a given amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS solution that I made is as follows

Here I create an animation that sets the **visibility** to **visible** on the start

```css
@keyframes effect {
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Then on the hover selector I add this animation where **effect** is the name
**1s**, is the duration (must be set so that the visibility is set,) **infinite** is making the animation go on until you get your mouse out of the element, and **2s** is the most important one here as it sets the delay.

```css
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  animation: effect 1s infinite 2s;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for to delay a server disconnect message in Shiny. Super helpful! Thank you